# Cross Object SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, cross-object

I have three objects

Object A - Parent
Object B - Child ( Lookup to A)
Object C - Child (Lookup to A)

B and C are not related directly, I have to fetch the fields from object C where my query is written on Object B.

Now, I have already a query written on Object B through which I am fetching some fields from Object A but not sure how can I modify it to fetch the fields from Object C or I have to write a separate query altogether to fetch the fields from C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationships between the object are as below

- ObjectB - No Parent
- ObjectA - Parent ObjectB
- ObjectC - Parent OjbectA

As per salesforce [soql limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits).

> In each specified relationship, only one level of parent-to-child
> relationship can be specified in a query.

Hence you have to use two different queries to get ObjectC records, if you want to keep existing query on objectB. Total 2 queries will be required to get data from all 3 objects.

**Workaround for single query:**

While taversing from child to parent you can go 5 levels up. By using middle object  ObjectA  you can get all 3 object fields.

**E.g**

```
SELECT 
    Id, Name, ..........,
    ObjectB.Id,  ObjectB.Name ........,
    (
        SELECT
            Id, Name,.....
            FROM
            ObjectC__r
    )
FROM ObjectA
```

Comment: Thanks, I was sensing the same that  I have to go through the separate query route. Appreciate your quick response.